# Ajax Call 404 Not Found

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, struts2

I am using Struts2 and I have following AJax code in Script Section

```
var url="../scriptWay/myCallToBackEnd.ac?myToy="+myToyInfo;
                        var respObj  = "";

                            new Ajax.Request(url,{
                              method : 'POST',
                              requestHeaders : {Accept:'application/json'},                        
                              onSuccess : function(resp){
                                    var jsonObj = resp.responseText.evalJSON(true);
                                    respObj  = jsonObj.respObj;

                            },
                           onException : function(resp){
                            console.log("Exceptionssssss.. "+resp);

                          },
                          onFailure : function(resp){

                          }

});
```

And this is Struts code..

```
 <action name="myCallToBackEnd.ac" class="BackEndClass" method="loadMethod">
                <result name="success" type="json">/jsp/ToysDetails.jsp</result>
            </action>
```

And this is Backend Method

```
public String loadMethod() throws Exception{
    Context contextObj = ContextHelper.getContext();
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) contextObj.getRequest();

    String myToys = request.getParameter("myToy");

    myToys = myToys+" Modfied with Description";

    MyToyClass myToysClassObj = new MyToyClass();
    myToysClassObj.setMyToysInfo(myToys);

    return SUCCESS; 
}
```

I Just want to access myTyosClassObj in my Returned JSP. And this is JSON response. Please help where I am wrong as it is showing Ajax 404 not FOUND.

Comment: A relative URL will be evaluated relative to the page in which the code is running. What is the full current page URL and what is the actual location of the endpoint?

Comment: Error itself describe the reason. The url you are requesting does not exist. Please correct it.

Comment: Use S2 tags to construct url.

Comment: If I am removing JSON REQ RESPONSE.. then it is WORKING... HOWWWW..???

Comment: BUT I want to do it through JSON only... Please help.. where I am wrong. Ajax URL is on relative Path only

Comment: create a baseUrl and then use it before making each url. This will also help you in production environment.                                                          var url = baseUrl + "/scriptWay/myCallToBackEnd.ac?myToy="+myToyInfo;

Comment: Yeah.IN Browser console also.. URL is looking fine to me. But why it is showing NOT FOUND.. I AM NOT GETTING

Answer (score 0):

Try to give full URL address..... I have solved same problem to my side.

```
var url="www.domainname.com/scriptWay/myCallToBackEnd.ac?myToy="+myToyInfo;
```

Hope it'll work

Comment: OKay.. got it...It is not showing 404 now. But it is showing something like         Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at "LINK". This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.

Comment: And one more thing. It is coming in onException section also... WHY.??

Comment: @user3095179 Is it a cross-domain request?